# Angular cli 7 + laravel con mysql, "error type: TypeError cannot read property of undefined" al intentar incluir en el html

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-cli, angular7

Yo soy bastante novato usando angular y me puse a hacer un crud con angular cli 7 y usando laravel y mysql como backend. El problema que tengo es que cuando intento traer los datos para mostrarlos en el html, me sale el error de la captura, pero los datos los estoy pudiendo traer correctamente y si intento registrar peliculas en la base de datos no tengo problemas.

Para mostrar los datos en el html lo hice asi {{pelicula.id}} (con {{pelicula?.id}} no me sale el error, pero tampoco me muestra nada en la table...)[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

aqui dejo la parte del home.component.ts para obtener los datos:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { PeliculasService } from '../servicios/peliculas.service';
import { Pelicula } from '../interfaces/pelicula';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-home',
  templateUrl: './home.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./home.component.css']
})
export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {

  Peliculas: Pelicula;

  constructor(private ServicioPeliculas: PeliculasService) { 
    this.ObtenerPeliculas();
  }

  ObtenerPeliculas(){
    this.ServicioPeliculas.get().subscribe(
      function(datos: Pelicula[])
      {
      this.Peliculas = datos;
      console.log(this.Peliculas);
      }, 
      function(error){
        console.log(error);
        alert("hubo un error");
      });
  }

  ngOnInit() {
  }
```

aqui la interface Pelicula:

```
import { GenericBrowserDomAdapter } from '@angular/platform-browser/src/browser/generic_browser_adapter';

export interface Pelicula{
    id?: number,
    nombre: string,
    director: string,
    actores: string,
    genero: string,
    created_at?: string,
    updated_at?: string
}
```

Y este es el servicio que usé para traer los datos:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Pelicula } from '../interfaces/pelicula';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class PeliculasService {

  API_ENDPOINT = 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/api';

  constructor(private ClienteHttp: HttpClient) { 
  }

  get(){
    return this.ClienteHttp.get(this.API_ENDPOINT + '/peliculas');
  }
```

Cualquier ayuda la apreciaría mucho.

Comment: Prueba a cambiar la declaración, Peliculas tendría que ser un array: `Peliculas: Pelicula[];`

Comment: Lo intenté pero me acabo de dar cuenta que el error está en que la funcion ObtenerPeliculas() retorna un void y no se porque... Tambien probé poner "return this.Peliculas = datos;" para ver si cambiaba algo pero no.

Answer (score 0):

1. Estas declarando Peliculas como un objeto `Pelicula` y no como un array `Pelicula[]`.
2. No estás inicializando Peliculas (que debería ser un array como ya dije) en el constructor. Sería algo como:

   ```
   constructor(private ServicioPeliculas: PeliculasService) { 
       this.Peliculas = []; // O this.Peliculas = new Array<Pelicula>();
       this.ObtenerPeliculas();
   }
   ```
3. Aclaro el punto 2. La carga de datos es asíncrona por lo que antes se debe inicializar la variable que va a contener los datos con un array vacío
   para que no haya problemas al utilizar dicha variable (por ejemplo en un `ngFor`) como un array mientras los datos cargan.